# Use fastapi with AWS websocket api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, fastapi

I have a FastAPI working on an EC2 under REST api with some endpoints. Now I would like to use it under a websocket api. To do this I have a few questions:

1. On my FastAPI, what shoud I do? I have read they introduce mangnum and a handler main for magnum, but they always have only one endpoint and I have several endpoints.
2. Also, they always use a lambda function. Could I use an EC2?
3. How do $connection and $disconnection work in this case? What do I have to introduce in my fastapi so I can still use my endpoints?

Processes inside my fastapi can take long to answer (eg. 20s). Therefore, I need to move to websocket to avoid timeouts. If you think I can have a better solution in a different way I'll happy to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent weeks on this same issue. I tried countless configurations and in the end I ended up not using FastAPI. I replaced my @app.websocket with a basic lambda_handler(event, context) function so that I could use the the connect, disconnect and sendmessage handlers as per AWS documentation. To the day I still can't figure out how to do it with FastAPI and it bugs me. Have you found a solution to this?

This helped - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/code-catalog-python-cross_service-apigateway_websocket_chat.html

Editing this to add that I am using python.

Comment: I think at the end I kind of understand it. Connect/disconnect are 2 endpoints, that you can use to tell your DB these users are using your FastAPI. Then, the third endpoint will take an argument, and using this argument in this endpoint you can redirect to the different endpoints you had. However, I ended by creating a queue for my system, which indeed was what I needed but I didn't know, so I start using Celery & Redis with a REST API without websockets and is working really well.